# OData connected service how to handle types

Tags: c#, types, json-deserialization, odata-v4

Maybe i'am missing something but i keep getting an exception on deserialization of a object. I think this is because of `@odata.context` being different than the `@odata.type`

For example if i do GET `~/MediaFiles` this is the response:

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://MyServer/odata/v1/$metadata#MediaFiles/ServerNamespace.Media.MediaFile",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#ServerNamespace.Media.MediaFile",
      ....
    }
  ]
}
```

But if i look at the MetaData:

```xml
<EntitySet Name="MediaFiles" EntityType="ServerNamespace.Media.FileItemInfo"/>
```

The error is on `DataServiceQuery.Take(10)` giving exception

```
InvalidOperationException: 
The response payload is a not a valid response payload. Please make sure that the top level element is a valid Atom or JSON element or belongs to 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/data' namespace.
```

And yes i checked if the body is valid JSON andalso if the headers are correct.

As you can see the MetaData describes type of `FileItemInfo` while the response JSON is of type `MediaFile`

Before someone asks, no i have no way to change or debug the servercode since this is a third party.

In this case i used the OData connected service to generate client code

Comment: Try Take(1) and see if it fails.  If you are getting to the point of taking 10 items than the format of the response is good and you are just getting less data than you expect.  I would also check the response status and see if you are getting a 200 OK or an error status.  Also check the body test to see if there is an error message.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, did Take(1) and also inspected the response code and body and all seems correct.

Comment: Are you getting 10 items?  Is all the items the same format?

Comment: Yes, also if i do Take(1) i get one item.

Comment: What does this have to do with vb.net?

Comment: @Mary That's because the `OData Connected Service` can generate Client Code in C# and VB.NET so i ways hoping to catch more fish by using both tags ;-)

Comment: What runtime is the server?  Also try setting the `Accept` request header to `"application/json;odata.metadata=minimal"`

Comment: This looks like the server implementation is not matching the published metadata (easy to do) Commonly occurs with M:N relationships or when the server implementation is manually constructed.

Comment: Does `MediaFile` inherit from `FileItemInfo` by any chance?

Comment: You should also include the C# query expression you are using, it will provide context that will allow us to post useful solutions.

Comment: @Gforse did you resolve this? there are workarounds, but if you post the server controller implementation (just the GET for MediaFiles) and the client side code, there are some simple workarounds on the client side, but ultimately its better to fix the server.